# Listening to an event sent using EventDispatcher class

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, events, actionscript

I created a custom event class, and a EventDispatcher-derived class.
What i did, is putting some logic in my EventDispatcher class, and then dispatched the custom event, the problem is i cant manage to listen to the event from my Main app.

I have an Arraycollection which i create and edit in the main app, than i want to send it to the EventDispatcher , and make a few checks, and than i want to dispatch my ArrayCollection back to main app for Binding with Visual objects.

If my entire code logic is incorrect, please tell me [=

Here is some code

The EventDispatcher sub-class

```
public class LoadData extends EventDispatcher
{
    public var sendData:DataSender = new DataSender('DataLoader',dataList,true);
    private var dataList:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();           
    dispatchEvent(sendData);
}
```

The custom Event class

```
public class DataSender extends Event {
    public var data:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection;
    public function DataSender(type:String, data:ArrayCollection, bubbles:Boolean=true, cancelable:Boolean=false)
    {
        super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

The Main app

```
var DataEvent:LoadData = new LoadData(dataList);
addEventListener('DataLoader',datacapture);


public function datacapture(event:DataSender):void{
    check.dataProvider = event.data;    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to make sure that the event is not dispatched before you actually listen to it. According to your code, it's not very clear when the event is dispatched.

Without going into the details of your logic, you could probably do something like this, please note that I'm not recommending this implementation, simply illustrating my answer!

```
    //In the LoadData Class
    public var sendData:DataSender = new DataSender('DataLoader',dataList,true);
    private var dataList:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();   

    public function dispatch():void
    {
       dispatchEvent(sendData);
    }

    //In your Main App
    var dataEvent:LoadData = new LoadData(dataList);
    dataEvent.addEventListener('DataLoader',datacapture);
    dataEvent.dispatch();
```

Comment: 10X!. May i ask why you dont recommend this implementation? is there a better why to do it? (im talking only about dispatching/listening to events). Im aware that the other parts of the code are also baddly written (just started learning action script)

Comment: Calling dispatchEvent() thru a public method doesn't look like such a good idea. Other than that, the implementation is pretty standard.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your code is royally messed up. First of all, I suggest you read up on Object Oriented Programming.

Then take a look at this:

```
public class LoadData extends EventDispatcher {

    public var sendData:DataSender;
    private var dataList:ArrayCollection;

    public function LoadData() {
        //This is the CONSTRUCTOR which is run when you do new LoadData()
    }

    //This function is called when you want to dispatch the event
    private function dispatch() {
        dataList = new ArrayCollection();           
        sendData = new DataSender('DataLoader',dataList,true);
        dispatchEvent(sendData);
    }

}
```

Then your main app is like this:

```
var dataEvent:LoadData = new LoadData(dataList);
dataEvent.addEventListener('DataLoader', datacapture);
```

Then, whenever the dataEvent.dispatch() function is called, your event handler will be invoked.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i did tried using it this way. In the "Main App" your presented, you actually listen to the EventDispetcher(dataEvent) and to the event itself(DataSender), is this the way to do it?

Comment: what's that?? Didn't understand what you're getting at